# Scikit-learn TruncatedSVD documentation

Tags: scikit-learn, nlp, svd, kaggle, lsa

I plan to use `sklearn.decomposition.TruncatedSVD` to perform LSA for a Kaggle
competition, I know the math behind SVD and LSA but I'm confused by
scikit-learn's user guide, hence I'm not sure how to actually apply
`TruncatedSVD`.

In [the doc](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/decomposition.html#truncated-singular-value-decomposition-and-latent-semantic-analysis), it states that:

> After this operation,

[image]

> `U_k * transpose(S_k)` is the transformed training set with `k` features (called `n_components` in the API)

Why is this? I thought after SVD, `X`, at this time `X_k` should be `U_k * S_k * transpose(V_k)`?

And then it says,

> To also transform a test set `X`, we multiply it with `V_k`: `X' = X * V_k`

What does this mean?

Answer (score 1):

I like the documentation [Here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.TruncatedSVD.html) a bit better.  Sklearn is pretty consistent in that you almost always use some kind of combination of the following code:

```
#import desired sklearn class
from sklearn.decomposition import TruncatedSVD 

trainData= #someArray
testData = #someArray

model = TruncatedSVD(n_components=5, random_state=42)
model.fit(trainData) #you fit your model on the underlying data
```

if you want to transform that data instead of just fitting it,

```
model.fit_transform(trainData) #fit and transform underlying data
```

Similarly, if you weren't transforming data, but making a prediction instead, you would use something like:

```
predictions =  model.transform(testData)
```

Hope that helps...

Comment: `---> 13 svd.predict(test)

AttributeError: 'TruncatedSVD' object has no attribute 'predict' `

Comment: Edited with `transform` instead of `predict`